# Changing the quality of the transient process in a nonlinear system (Part III)

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

My question is a continuation of the topics:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3910814/changing-the-quality-of-the-transient-process-in-a-nonlinear-system-in-mathemat?noredirect=1&lq=1

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923222/changing-the-quality-of-the-transient-process-in-a-nonlinear-system-part-ii/3929273#3929273

I have gradient dynamic like this:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}$

where:
$f$ - Any function that has one extreme (minimum or maximum). For example $f = e^{-(x - x_{*})^2}$

$x$ - variable of the differential equation.

$x_{*}$ - the point at which the maximum or minimum of the function $f$ is reached.

Parameters: $x(0)=-1$, $x_{*}=1$

The solution is to go from the starting point $x(0)$ to the point $x_{*}$ at which the minimum or maximum of the function $f(t)$ is reached:

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xstart = -1, xextremum = 1}

extr = Exp[-(x[t] - xextremum)^2]

sys = NDSolve[{x'[t] == D[extr, x[t]], x[0] == xstart}, {x}, {t, 0, 
   500}]

Plot[{Evaluate[(x[t]) /. sys], 
  Evaluate[(xstart - xextremum) Exp[-t] + xextremum]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

The original solution is shown in blue. I want transients in such a gradient system to occur exponentially. (as shown in orange). Those. the transition from starting point $x(0)$ to the point $x_{*}$ must be described by the formula:

$x(t)=(x(0)−x_{*}) \cdot exp(-t) + x_{*} + \alpha \cdot sin(\omega t)$,

$x_{*}$ - unknown in advance. Finding this point is the task of the gradient system.

How do I modify the original differential equation?

Comment: I cannot figure out what is being asked here.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find a $f$ that makes the solution of $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}$$ satisfy $$x(t)=(x(0)−x_{*}) \cdot \exp(-t) + x_{*} + \alpha \cdot \sin(\omega t)$$?

Comment: @xzczd
No! $f$ is a function that has one minimum or maximum. We know it. Let's take a $e^{-(x - x_{*})^2}$ for example and substitute it into the original gradient ODE.
I gave the code from Mathematica for the numerical solution above. In such a system, the transition from the start point $x_0$ to the end point $x_{*}$ is carried out along the curve, which is shown in blue in the picture. How to make the transition from one state to another occur exponentially?

Comment: @xzczd
We may to add either an additional input signal, or an additional ODE, which includes the variable $x$ and its derivatives, or include an additional variable, for example $y$.

Comment: …So, you want to find an ODE whose solution is $x(t)=(x(0)−x_{*}) \cdot \exp(-t) + x_{*} + \alpha \cdot \sin(\omega t)$?

Comment: It is necessary that the original gradient equation either satisfies or tends to it (for example, if we introduce an additional gain $k$ into the system). The more $k$, the closer the solution of the gradient equation to the desired transient. I will add right away that $x_{*}$ is unknown in advance, but it is searched for in the course of the gradient system. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Well, then `x'[t] - D[extr, x[t]] == (-E^-t (-1 - xextremum) + 
 2 E^-(-1 + E^-t (-1 - xextremum) + xextremum)^2 (-1 + E^-t (-1 - xextremum) + 
    xextremum))/k` where `k==1` is such an ODE, isn't it? When `k -> Infinity` it tends to `x'[t] - D[extr, x[t]] == 0`.

Comment: But what if the position of the extremum and the structure of the function itself are not known in advance, but we can measure it and its gradient?

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder. Since you can measure the function, just use e.g. `Interpolation` to build a function using the measured data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general exponential solution to your equation: `y''[x]+y'[x]==0` is:

```
-E^-x C[1] + C[2]
```

Therefore, we have 2 free parameters. You may determine them e.g. by specifying the start- and endpoints. E.g. name the start point {x0,y0} and the point of the extremum {x1,y1}, then we get:

```
Solve[{-E^-x0 C[1] + C[2 ] == y0, -E^-x1 C[1] + C[2 ] == y1}, {C[1], C[2 ]}]

(*{{C[1] -> -((E^(x0 + x1) (y0 - y1))/(-E^x0 + E^x1)), 
  C[2] -> (-E^x0 y0 + E^x1 y1)/(-E^x0 + E^x1)}}*)
```

Comment: By the way, I poorly understood your answer. My ODE is $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}$. I need to make the transients in such a system occur exponentially. The only suggestion I had was to add an additional condition $x^{''}+x^{'}=0$ by embedding it in the original ODE. How to do it? We can do anything - additional input signals $u$ and expansion to the ODE system.

Comment: Well, you can not have a single function to fulfill 2 independent equations. Either it is x'== some given function or x''+x'==0. With an equation of first order, you have 1 parameter free, with a second order 2 parameters. ;Maybe you need to explain your full problem.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2prf.jpg

It seems to me that I have fully disclosed the problem. It is reflected in this figure. Blue is the solution to the original equation. Orange is what it should be.